# How to show inequality $|t c^n-(1-t)|p(ce^{2\pi i s})||>0$ for a complex polynomial $p$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Considere a complex polinomial $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1 z+a_0$ and define:

$$c=|a_{n-1}|+\ldots+|a_1|+|a_0|+1.$$ Then we can show:

$$|p(ce^{2\pi is})|\leq \frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c-1},$$ for every $s\in I=[0, 1]$.

Using this I'd like to show:

$$|t c^n -(1-t)|p(ce^{2\pi i s})||>0,$$
for every $t\in I=[0, 1]$.

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

THanks!

Comment: You have unbalanced absolute value signs so it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: I've fixed that.

Comment: What took you so long? Anyway, you just have to show that you can't have the expression in the absolute value signs equal to 0. But I'm sure you thought of that.

Comment: Sure, but it didn't take me too far.

Comment: there is something wrong here as fixing $s$, we have $f(t)=tc^n-(1-t)|p(ce^{2\pi i s})|$ is a real continuous function in $t \in [0,1]$ that takes opposite values at $t=0, t=1$ so it must be zero somewhere